# Heroku doesn't re-deploy my app when I git merge

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I have been push useless commits just to ensure heroku reloads and redeploys my app after using git merge to make changes to master. Am I missing something?

EDIT
Im deploying straight from git. Hence no git push heroku master.

Comment: did you run `git push heroku master` ?

Comment: I mean heroku will only redeploy when you push changes ( not only commit ) to the `master` branch `heroku` remote.

Comment: I pushed to dev than merged dev to master. So mater branch got updated. However heroku didnt seem to noticed that master has changes and didnt redeploy!

Comment: So after you merge to `master` you have to push changes to the remote repo. Yes, remote repo does not 'see' any changes until you `push` them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your changes appear in the remote repo, you have to `push` them. Your normal dev cycle should be:

- Create a branch

  `git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH`
- Work & commit changes

  `git commit -am "commit message"`
- if you work in the same branch with your teammates, then you can push changes to the remote repo, but it will only push to that branch

  `git push REMOTE_REPO NEW_BRANCH`
- Merge your branch to `master` branch

  `git checkout master`

  `git merge NEW_BRANCH`
- Push changes to the remote

  `git push <REMOTE_NAME> master`

which in your case`REMOTE_NAME` is `heroku`, so

```
git push heroku master
```

should send all your commits to deploy to heroku

Comment: Ohhh i think i failed to mention im deploying straight from get hence i cant push to heroku master

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.
Under the deploy tab in heroku i can choose to deploy manually from my git branch as seen below.

[image]